# Find $\int \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^2-2}}$

Tags: calculus, integration

$\int \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^2-2}}$

My book says to solve this using $x = 1/t$ so I did $dx = -1/t^2$

$$-\int\frac{\frac{1}{t^2}}{t\sqrt{1-2t^2}} = -\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2t^2}} = -\arcsin(\sqrt{2t})=-\arcsin(\sqrt{2}/x)$$

My book says the solution is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\arccos(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{x}).$ What went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, remember integration constants: $\arcsin y=\frac{\pi}{2}-\arccos y$. Secondly, be careful with coefficients: $\sqrt{1/t^2-2}=\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1/(2t^2)-1}$.

Comment: Didn't know about that one, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What went wrong is you forgot to pull out the constant:
$$-\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2t^2}}\mathrm{d}t=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac 12-t^2}}\mathrm{d}t $$
then you continue with the arcsine.

Also, there's technically two cases (assuming we're working in real numbers): $x>0$ and $x<0$. What you did is the first case. In the second case, the integral is
$$\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2t^2}}\mathrm{d}t $$ so the antiderivative is the same except for a minus sign.

**Update**: With the substitution $u=\sqrt{x^2-2}$, the integral becomes
$$\int\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{u^2+2} $$
and there's no need for cases with this one.